# Qual a finalidade do ";;" em OCaml?

Tags: funções, característica-linguagem, ocaml

Atualmente estou estudando OCaml, mais especificamente sobre a sintaxe de funções. Entretanto, me surgiu uma duvida a respeito do símbolo `;;` no qual tenho que informar no final da chamada da minha função como ilustro no exemplo abaixo:

```
let soma a b = a + b
let res = soma 10 10;;
Printf.printf "Resultado da soma: %d\n" res
```

Caso eu remover o `;;` eu recebo este error:

```
18 | let res = soma 10 10
               ^^^^
Error: This function has type int -> int -> int
       It is applied to too many arguments; maybe you forgot a `;'.
```

Agora veja, que também posso colocar ele no final da declaração da minha função:

```
let soma a b = a + b;;
```

Que o compilador não vai reclamar.

## Duvida

Qual é a finalidade do `;;` quando usado em funções?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

O duplo ponto e vírgula `;;` em OCaml é necessário para que haja o processamento dos dados de entrada pelo **REPL** para dizê-lo que ele deve avaliar (executar) uma expressão, não sendo uma característica obrigatória da linguagem. Não é obrigatório seu uso ao escrever código-fonte OCaml que serão posteriormente compilados, embora possam ser usados sem problemas a às vezes seja útil incluir `;;` para melhorar o relatório de erros do OCaml,
tornando mais explícito onde uma determinada declaração deveria terminar.

Estou deduzindo que você está usando um REPL para fazer os testes, pois depois de avaliar uma expressão, o REPL primeiro imprime o tipo do resultado e
em seguida, imprime o próprio resultado.

Um programa OCaml é uma sequência de declarações, seguidas por uma expressão principal. Você deve usar o duplo `;;` para **separar as linhas de declarações** das **linhas de expressão principal** ao executar em um REPL.

No seu exemplo, as linhas de declarações são:

```
let soma a b = a + b
let res = soma 10 10
```

E a linha de execução principal:

```
Printf.printf "Resultado da soma: %d\n" res
```

Por isso foi necessário o inserir em `let res = soma 10 10;;`. Porém, o uso do `;;` não se restringi a funções. Você pode usá-lo para separar qualquer linha de declaração de uma linha de execução. Veja como exemplo:

```
let soma a b = a + b
let res = soma 10 10
let numeros: string = "10, 10";;

Printf.printf "Resultado da soma: %d\n" res;
Printf.printf "Foi usado os valores: %s\n" numeros
```

`let numeros: string = "10, 10";;` não é uma função, apenas uma declaração direta de uma variável do tipo *string*. Outro detalhe é que não é necessário usá-lo imediatamente após `"10, 10"`. Você poderia escrever facilmente destas formas:

```
let soma a b = a + b
let res = soma 10 10
let numeros: string = "10, 10"      

;;

Printf.printf "Resultado da soma: %d\n" res;
Printf.printf "Foi usado os valores: %s\n" numeros
```

Ou:

```
let soma a b = a + b
let res = soma 10 10
let numeros: string = "10, 10"
  

;;Printf.printf "Resultado da soma: %d\n" res;
Printf.printf "Foi usado os valores: %s\n" numeros
```

Faça os testes no playgroung [TryOCaml](https://try.ocamlpro.com/).

Não há necessidades de adicionar `;;` nas declarações `let`, pois o REPL meio que faz isso implicitamente. Se você altera seu exemplo e associar o `Printf.printf "Resultado da soma: %d\n" res` em alguma declaração, o programa funciona normalmente, mesmo sem explicitamente adicionar `;;`:

```
let soma a b = a + b
let res = soma 10 10
let print: unit = Printf.printf "Resultado da soma: %d\n" res
```

Saída no TryOCaml:

```
# let soma a b = a + b ;;
val soma : int -> int -> int = <fun>
# let res = soma 10 10 ;;
val res : int = 20
# let print: unit = Printf.printf "Resultado da soma: %d\n" res ;;
Resultado da soma: 20
val print : unit = ()
```

<sup>`#` indica a linha executada pelo REPL, seguido logo abaixo a saída dos dados incluindo sua tipagem.</sup>

---

Nota: No CAML Light, o predecessor do OCaml, o ponto `;;` era obrigatório. Por esta razão, eles são bastante comuns em código antigo originalmente escrito em CAML Light ou escrito nos primeiros dias de OCaml. Hoje em dia eles são considerados um estilo ruim. <sup>[Fonte](https://baturin.org/docs/ocaml-faq/#heading_toc_j_1)</sup>

---

#### E o simples `;`?

Talvez um ponto bem relevante em relação à pergunta que vale a pena ser citado. Diferente do `;;` que indica a separação de uma declaração de expressão principal, ou seja, um terminador de expressões, o `;` é um **separador de instruções**. Você pode concatenar instruções em uma mesma função.

Exemplo:

```
let soma a b = Printf.printf "Valores -> a: %d, b: %d\n" a b ; a + b
let res = Printf.printf "Fazendo a soma agora...\n";soma 10 10
    
;;
Printf.printf "Resultado da soma: %d\n" res
```

Na função `soma`, por exemplo, o `;` foi usado para adicionar uma ação de print antes de fazer a soma dos argumentos:

```
let soma a b = Printf.printf "Valores -> a: %d, b: %d\n" a b ;  a + b
               |_________________ print _____________________|_ soma _|
```

Saída no TryOCaml:

```
# let soma a b = Printf.printf "Valores -> a: %d, b: %d\n" a b; a + b ;;
val soma : int -> int -> int = <fun>
# let res = Printf.printf "Fazendo a soma agora...\n";soma 10 10

;;
Fazendo a soma agora...
Valores -> a: 10, b: 10
Resultado da soma: 20
val res : int = 20
# Printf.printf "Resultado da soma: %d\n" res ;;
- : unit = ()
```

Comment: Existe a possibilidade de copiar a saída? Digo isso para evitar imagens.

Comment: No `try.ocamlpro.com` basta arrastar o cursor de baixo para cima (pode ser ao contrário também) até o texto de interesse (inicial ou final) e **antes de soltar** o clique esquerdo pressione o direito do mouse/rato, vai aparecer o contextmenu do navegador, irá poder copiar a partir disso. Observação, a alternativa de playground que pode experimentar também é o https://ocaml.org/play